# how to create order sequence in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have below requirement in oracle :

```
date        account     client  Balance
01-Mar-23   1           1       1
01-Mar-23   1           1       2
01-Mar-23   2           1       1
01-Mar-23   2           2       3
01-Mar-23   2           2       4
01-Mar-23   2           2       5
01-Mar-23   3           1       3
```

for this type of data i need to add ordering columns like below

```
date        account     client  Balance Order
01-Mar-23   1           1           1   1
01-Mar-23   1           1           2   2
01-Mar-23   2           1           1   1
01-Mar-23   2           2           3   1
01-Mar-23   2           2           4   2
01-Mar-23   2           2           5   3
01-Mar-23   3           1           6   1
```

i tried used ROW_NUMBER() over using date/account/client but the order is coming as below:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

can any one help me

Comment: please edit the question and show your query. Better yet, setup a test case on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and share that.

Answer (score 2):

Not able to reproduce your problem. Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to partition and order by, so making an assumption here...

```
select o_date, account, client, balance, 
  row_number() over (partition by account, client order by o_date) as rn
from my_table
```

| O_DATE | ACCOUNT | CLIENT | BALANCE | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-MAR-23 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 01-MAR-23 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 01-MAR-23 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 01-MAR-23 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 01-MAR-23 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 01-MAR-23 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 01-MAR-23 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y0__zstj)

Given the sample dates do not include timestamps, the behavior is unknown.